"RX ring buffer full" error in PySerial despite flushing buffers
I'm working on a project where I use the PySerial module to communicate with a battery management system (BMS) through a serial port. I'm also using ThingsBoard and Streamlit in this project. However, I keep encountering the "RX ring buffer full" error, even though I am flushing the buffers each time. Additionally, the lines I read are different every time I run the code.
import serial
import csv
from time import sleep

responseArray = list()

def writeBatteryData(rest_client, batteryUsed):
"""Writes the battery attributes' values to the connected BMS

    Args:
        batteryUsed (str): Battery used in the battery instance
    
    Returns:
        None
    """
    with open('deviceForms/batteryForm.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvForm = csv.reader(csvfile)
        form = list(csvForm)
        numRows = len(form)
    
    batteryForm = getDeviceAttributes(rest_client, batteryUsed, form, numRows)
    start = 0
    for start in range(numRows):
        if form[start][0] == 'Charge Overcurrent':
            break
    
    with open('deviceForms/batteryThingSetCommands.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        csvForm = csv.reader(csvfile)
        batteryCommandsForm = list(csvForm)
    
    ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyACM1', baudrate=115200, timeout=5)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    ser.reset_output_buffer()
    ser.write(b'select thingset\r\n')
    response = ser.readline()
    
    for i in range(start, numRows):
        ser.write((batteryCommandsForm[i-start][1] + str(batteryForm[i][1]) + '}\r\n').encode())
        sleep(0.1)
        response = ser.readline()
        responseArray.append(response)
        sleep(0.1)
        # Flushing buffer using read()
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            data = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
    
    ser.close()
    print(responseArray)

writeBatteryData(rest_client, "NMCBattery")

I've tried to ensure the buffer is flushed by using ser.reset_input_buffer() and ser.reset_output_buffer(), and by reading any remaining data with ser.read(ser.in_waiting). However, the issue persists.
Questions:
1.Why am I still encountering the "RX ring buffer full" error despite flushing the buffers?
2.Why are the lines I read different every time?

